# Reopen one of my questions - Invalid Duplicate Marked

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, incorrectly-closed

> Related: [How do I disable the boot splash screen, and only show kernel and boot text instead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33416/how-do-i-disable-the-boot-splash-screen)

Okay, so this was marked as a duplicate, apparently, but I only noticed this now.  Is the marked duplicate the same as what I was asking?  I was asking at the time how to disable the boot splash screen in order to see kernel output during boot.  I did *not* ask how to disable X loading automatically, because I want to see the kernel output during boot then continue to load X and GNOME/Unity.

I'm thinking this is *wrongly* marked as a duplicate because the "duplicate" is asking how to disable GUI boot altogether, which is *not* what my question was asking.

I'd like that reopened rather than left marked as a dupe.  Besides, it already has a *good answer that answers the question* and that answer has a +20 vote on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been resolved, and the question has been reopened.  Thank you to those who cast reopen votes to undo the dupe marking on my question.

And thanks to [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) for modifying the tags on my question to remove version specific tags.

Comment: My bad! Glad you got it sorted quickly.